# Check box value remaining after this.form.reset clear

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have this script to add up some check box values

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
    Total = 0;
    totaltest.innerText = Total;
}

function checkoptionone(checkbox) {
    checknum = parseFloat(checkbox.value);
    if (checkbox.checked == true) {
        Total += checknum;
    } else {
        Total -= checknum;
    }
    totaltest.innerText = Total;
}
    </script>
```

I can get the values of the check boxes in my equation in another function...but when i clear (i have a button with this.for.reset) the value for the checked (now uncked because of clear) remains....it will only go away if i uncheck the box before i press clear...I know what the problem is i just dont know how to fix it...I tried to add a function to the button (like the function for the checkboxes so that it would just do the same function without a box having to be check to activate the function) but i think the this.form.reset trumps everything...i dont know...any ideas??

Comment: There is a similar problem, covered here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9065931/jquery-recheck-checkboxes-after-clearing-them-with-remoteattr

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$('form').find('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

in combination with $('form').reset();